# Issues with Visual Studio 2017 exe file opening and closing immediately.. Now being able to view it properly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So I recently started using Visual Studio 2017 for my C# class.

I recently created a code that I saved and wanted to see if it work properly. So I build the solution and it went successfully. I looked up the application(exe) file and opened it but immediately the command prompt would close so i don't even get a chance to view that the code worked. Is there anything I can do so I can view the code in the command prompt and properly run it so i can see it work correctly.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Quick Note: I tried doing ctrl + f5 key to run the program but for some reason it doesn't work on my laptop nor do anything

Comment: Some general thoughts: 1) Add `Console.ReadLine()` to the end of your program to prevent window from closing. 2) First open a command prompt then run your app.exe from the command prompt -- command prompt will not close when app process exits. 3) Add logging/tracing to your application to see what is being executed.  4) Adding a `Debugger.Launch();` statement should allow you to attach and debug your application.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the program actually finishes and therefore closes. Adding a

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

at the end of your program will require an enter key press before closing.

Comment: it worked.. Thank You So Much!